# How Do You Thread an External Hanging API Call in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, ipfs

Getting the specifics out of the way, I'm writing an open source P2P social network over IPFS and Flask -- I know, it's been done. I'm choosing Flask because pyinstaller can put it in an exe file.

I am attempting to update my IPNS every 10 minutes to publish all status updates I've added to the network during said 10 minutes. The cron function from setup class (from library.py) is where that updater function is stored. At first, I threaded the cron function from **init** of setup. The server hung. Then I moved the threading process over to app.before_first_request. The server still hangs.

https://pastebin.com/bXHTuH83 (main.py)

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from library import *

#=========================TO BE DELETED=========================================
def pretty(json):
    json = dumps(loads(json), indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    return json
#===============================================================================

app = Flask(__name__)

GANN = setup()

@app.before_first_request
def cron_job():
    Thread(target=GANN.cron())

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello World!!!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port="80", debug=True, threaded=True)
```

https://pastebin.com/W5P8Tpvd (library.py)

```
from threading import Thread
from time import time, sleep
import urllib.request
from json import loads, dumps

def api(*argv, **kwargs):
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/"
    for arg in argv:
        arg = arg.replace(" ", "/")
        if arg[:-1] != "/":
            arg += "/"
        url += arg
    url = url[0:-1]
    if kwargs:
        url+="?"
        for val in kwargs:
            url = url + val + "=" + kwargs[val] + "&"
        url = url[0:-1]
        print(url)
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=300) as response:
            return response.read()
    except:
        return b"""{"ERROR": "CANNOT CONNECT TO IPFS!"}"""

class setup():

    def __init__(self):
        api("files", "mkdir", arg="/GANN", parents="True")
        self.root_hash = ""

    def update_root(self):
        try:
            for entry in loads(api("files", "ls", l="True").decode())["Entries"]:
                if entry["Name"] == "GANN":
                    self.root_hash = entry["Hash"]
        except:
            return """{"ERROR": "CANNOT FIND ROOT DIRECTORY"}"""

    def publish_root(self):
        api("name", "publish", arg=self.root_hash)

    def cron(self):
        while True:
            print("CRON Thread Started!")
            self.update_root()
            self.publish_root()
            sleep(600)
```

I have searched the web for a couple days and have yet to find a threading technique that will split from the main process and not hang the server from taking other requests. I believe I'm on a single stream connection, as IPFS blocks connections to every other device in my home when it's started. It takes a couple minutes for the CLI IPNS update to go through, so I set urllib's timeout to 300 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what I think the threading code is not correct.

```
@app.before_first_request
def cron_job():
    Thread(target=GANN.cron())
```

Here you created a `Thread` object. The argument must be `callable`, but you called your method already here. so the right way would be

```
Thread(target=GANN.cron)
```

So the thread can call the `cron` function later. having said that, the `Thread` must be started, so it will call the function target you gave. So it must be ike

```
thread_cron = Thread(target=GANN.cron)
thread_cron.start()
```

Since you called the `GANN.cron()` , the method starts executing and your app hung!

Comment: Need not. Its a silly mistake every one makes at least once in life !!! Did it solve the problem?

Comment: Yes. I've been looking for the solution to this for 2 days and called the method because the object wouldn't run :'(. Thank you.